# How can I internally point to a domain but keep the url with the subdomain constant?

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have a domain www.example.com hosted in one location.

I have created another account with a different hosting provider that allows me to create subdomains: www.test1.example.com and www.test2.example.com

I am putting a custom page for each of the subdomains when the user goes to test1.example.com, test2.example.com....

After the user logs in on this custom page, I want to maintain the subdomain (of test1.example.com) but internally have all requests point to www.example.com.

I am running the custom pages on Apache and the domain pages on Apache Tomcat - I think that using 'mod_rewrite' is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a .htaccess file in your subdomain's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [redirect,last]
```

To enable mod_rewrite on a modern Ubuntu web server run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```

Make sure AllowOverride is set to "All" in your VirtualHost configuration (for example /etc/apache2/sites-available/default):

```
<Directory /var/www/document/root/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

then restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Some more information: I'm running the main 'www.example.com' in a windows azure virtual environment. Also, doesn't your suggestion 'redirect' the page (including changing the URL). I want to maintain the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically the answer I found that worked was to use mod_proxy. I enabled that as an Apache module and included the following in my httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "location_of_the_custom_page"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "D:\wamp\www\capitalfloat">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
    Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost2
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I also had to include 'http://www.example.com' and 'test1.example.com' in the Windows Host File (For me, C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). In my custom login page, the request goes to 'example.com' and all subsequent requests are sent to 'www.example.com' but the url still shows 'test1.example.com/...'